# Coroutine api call only finishes after a thread sleep

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to the concept of Coroutines. now I got this problem, when I call my Coroutine function it gives an empty object back when I DON'T use 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();. But when I use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int); It waits until the sleep method is completed before continuing the code. I get that it probably has something to do with that they work on the same thread but even my debug functions before the sleep method won't print untill the sleep function is done. could really use some help here!

I tried it with synchronous calls but this just makes my layout freeze.

```cs
IEnumerator PostRequestBearerToken(string uri)
    {
        string authorization = APIHelpers.authenticate("user", "pass");
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("grant_type", "client_credentials");

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, form))
        {
            www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Post request complete!" + " Response Code: " + www.responseCode);
                string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("Response Text:" + responseText);
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

                //deserialize bearertoken
                BearerObject myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<BearerObject>(www.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log("json : " + myObject.ToString());
                //BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance();
                BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance().SetBearerToken(myObject);
                Debug.Log(BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance().GetBearerToken().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

```cs
void Update()
   {
       if (!loadFirstFrame)
       {
           loadFirstFrame = true;
       }
       else if (loadFirstFrame)
       {
           StartCoroutine(PostRequestBearerToken(APIHelpers.bearerString));

           //go to next scene            
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
           SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
       }

   }
```

Comment: First of all you should not use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`. Please use a timer with Time.deltaTime

Comment: @Jichael thanks for the feedback, but just for testing purpose I used this methode

Comment: @Jichael Or a coroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the `SceneManager.LoadScene` method. Coroutines run in separate threads. Since you start the coroutine and immediately load a new scene, there is no time to run the coroutine before the current scene (and script object) is unloaded. The `Thread.Sleep` call introduces a delay that gives enough time for the coroutine to finish before the scene load.

To get around this, you can use a flag (actually I use two, so you don't kick off the coroutine multiple times):

```
private bool _postComplete = false;
private bool _startedPost = false;

IEnumerator PostRequestBearerToken(string uri)
{
    string authorization = APIHelpers.authenticate("user", "pass");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, form))
    {
        www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Post request complete!" + " Response Code: " + www.responseCode);
            string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log("Response Text:" + responseText);
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

            //deserialize bearertoken
            BearerObject myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<BearerObject>(www.downloadHandler.text);
            Debug.Log("json : " + myObject.ToString());
            //BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance();
            BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance().SetBearerToken(myObject);
            Debug.Log(BearerTokenSingleton.getInstance().GetBearerToken().ToString());
        }
        _postComplete = true;
    }
}
```

And then use that in the `Update` method:

```
   void Update()
   {
       if (!loadFirstFrame)
       {
           loadFirstFrame = true;
       }
       else if (loadFirstFrame)
       {
           if (!_startedPost)
           {
               StartCoroutine(PostRequestBearerToken(APIHelpers.bearerString));
               _startedPost = true;
           }         

           if (_postComplete)
               SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
       }
   }
```

Comment: An alternative is to call SceneManager.LoadScene(2); in the Coroutine at the end.

Comment: @Ron Beyer thanks it works! now i still got an unanswerd question. I quote "Coroutines run in separate threads" so why don't my log functions print any output aslong as the sleep method is active ? doesn't the sleep methode makes the Mainthread sleep but not the Coroutine thread ?

Comment: @LiefLayer thanks for the feedback, but after the first Coroutine and the nextscene methode has to come more code. i just deleted it for the purpose of this question. it doesn't contribute to the scope of this question.

Comment: @AnthonyHeremans when you load a new scene your code will start from the Awake/Start method (only if your object is in the next scene). I don't really see the point of using code after the LoadScene execute (at least right now without trying the code).

Comment: @LiefLayer i misstyped, i ment: [...]after the first Coroutine and before the nextscene methode[...]

Comment: @AnthonyHeremans Ok now it's clear. But I still think is not really safe. You cannot be sure that the code after the Coroutine and before the LoadScene is all executed. Because the LoadScene stop any code execution and your Coroutine could be faster than your "before LoadScene code". Even if you don't want to port all your code inside the Coroutine, you should really move in the if (_postComplete) before the LoadScene to avoid unexpected behaviour